# Why displaying link of a video by using wp_trim_words in front end by setting a video in post content?

Tags: php, wordpress, themes, theme-development

[this is front end view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIpPW.png)I want to trim the words of post content that's why I used wp_trim words. But when I include a video in post content then it shows the video link and trimmed text in the frontend. I want to show the video not the video link trimmed text in the frontend. To solve the problem what can be used instead of wp_trim_words?

here is my code below

```
<div class="post-body">
 <?php echo wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 25, ''); ?>
 <p>
  <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="btn btn-color btn- 
  sm">Read More</a>
</p>
```

Comment: `get_the_content` does not apply the normal content filter, see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_content/#more-information - so you’l probably have to do that yourself in this case (`apply_filters` can be used for that.)

Comment: How to apply this? Can you please show, Thanks in advance. I want to display the video and also trimmed text in front end